# How to calculate all my input

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, input, static

Hello I have two type of input dynamic and static. I want to calculate them and show the total in other input.

Here is my static input

```
<input step="any" type="number" readOnly id="totallundi" class="totallundi"
       name="totallundi" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0" onblur="autre();" 
       onfocus="enter();"/>
```

Here my button to add dynamic input

```
<p id="add_lundi" class="plus">
    <a href="#"><span> + </span></a>
</p>
<p id="remove_lundi" class="minus">
    <a href="#"><span> - </span></a>
</p>
```

Here is my function in javascript to make new row dynamic

```
var counter = 0;
var $newRow; 

$(function(){
    $('#add_field').click(function(){
        counter += 1;

        $('#calculTempsdiv').append(
            $('<input id="temps' + counter + '" name="temps[]" type="number" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0" step="any" onchange="checkField();" class="dynamic" onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/>')  
        )
    });
});
```

how do I calculate them and show it into here :

```
<input step="any" type="number" id="totaldimanche" class="totaldimanche" 
       readOnly name="totaldimanche" size="10" min="0" max="24" value="0" 
       onblur="autre();" onfocus="enter();"/>
```

**EDIT**

here how I calculate my static one for the moment and its doest take my static ( i didnt show all my input over so totaldimanche is exist totallundi exist but i didnt show you my input over in the code cause its all the same.

```
$('document').ready(function() {



    $(
        '#totaldimanche,#totallundi, #totalmardi, #totalmercredi , #totaljeudi, #totalvendredi ,#totalsamedi, #input1,#input2,#temps3,#input4,#input5,#input6,#tempsam  '
    ).each(function()   {$(this).on('change',recalculate);}
       );

});

function recalculate()
{

    if(isNaN(this.value))
       alert("Please enter a number");

    else
    {

   var b = 0; 

     if ( 
     ( $('#totaldimanche').val() !== b)  
     &&   ( $('#totallundi').val() !== b   )
     &&    ($('#totalmardi').val() !== b   )
     &&    ($('#totalmercredi').val() !== b   )
     &&    ($('#totaljeudi').val() !== b   )
     &&   ( $('#totalvendredi').val() !== b   )   
     &&   ( $('#totalsamedi').val() !== b ))
     {

        var a = 40;

        var value1 = $('#totaldimanche').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totaldimanche').val());
        var value2 = $('#totallundi').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totallundi').val());
        var value3 = $('#totalmardi').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totalmardi').val());
        var value4 = $('#totalmercredi').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totalmercredi').val());
        var value5 = $('#totaljeudi').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totaljeudi').val());
        var value6 = $('#totalvendredi').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totalvendredi').val());
        var value7 = $('#totalsamedi').val() == "" ? 0 :  parseFloat($('#totalsamedi').val());
        var total =  value1 + value2 + value3  + value4 + value5 + value6 + value7 ;

        $('#result').val(total);
```

Comment: trying to help - but it is hard to visualize what you are trying to do. It would be best to see it in a jsbin or jsfiddle. This was my original. This was my original work on the answer to your question. [link to jsbin-example](http://jsbin.com/ridiz/1/edit) Created an add and subtract feature to your input text field.

Comment: Here and exemple http://cjoint.com/14mi/DEqwD0PDBfw.htm what i Want if its doest clear I'll explain : So Make the total of the day in the grey input. After make the total of all grey input( total of the week) in the last input.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use the [length property](http://api.jquery.com/length/) and show the value on your input.

You can add it in your function after add a new dynamic input.

EDIT:

You are appending a new input that has an id equal to temps + increment and it has a class that it's name is dynamic. If you want to know the number of inputs that are dynamic then you only need to call a function that counts then. You can create a new function `countDynamicInputs()` and call it on your click function after apending the new input.

```
function countDynamicInput() {

    $(".dynamic").length;

}
```

Seeing your code I don't see any other way to count the dynamic inputs as you do for static inputs because you only set an id that is temps + increment and a class that is dynamic. If you want to count the inputs as you do for the static inputs you should look a way to set the days in the dynamic inputs.

EDIT2:

You said "I want to calculate them and show the total in other input." I understand it as you want to know the number of dynamic inputs. If you want to get the value then you need to use the [each iterator](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) on your dynamic inputs and get its value and sum them.

You can apply the each into the dynamic class to get all that inputs and for each iteration get the value.

Comment: Right now I have a function who calculate only static input and not my dynamic one when it change I'll edit my question you can see

Comment: I need to count the number in the input not count how many i have input . if in the input1(dynamic) i have the number 10 in + input2dynamic  number exemple 5 in) will show in the total 15